# HHVM through Apache mod_fastcgi on debian

Tags: apache, debian, mod-fastcgi, hhvm

I've been able to rather easily get facebooks hhvm working from prebuilt debian packages as well as compile it, and afterwards to run it behind apache as a proxy. The problem with the proxy setup is though, that I can't get response headers other than http status code 200 - like 304 for example - through. It's not the proxy config of apache, but something wrt hhvm and apache interact, or even in hhvm.

Anyway, HHVM officially stopped supporting the standalone server, and they're moving over to fastcgi, and as all of our servers are running Debian, I don't have access to mod_proxy_fastcgi without compiling it (the only backports I found of apache 2.4 don't have mod_proxy_fastcgi backported unfortunately).

So I'm currently trying to get HHVM to run behind the old mod_fastcgi with apache 2.2. But currently I'm only getting "connect() failed" in the error log of apache, while hhvm is listening on `:::1080`

The important part of my apache config is

```
RemoveHandler application/x-httpd-php

FastCgiExternalServer /home/www/hhvm/hostname/htdocs/php5.fcgi -flush -host ip6-localhost:1080
AddType application/x-hhtpd-fastphp5 .php
Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php5.fcgi
Alias /php5.fcgi /home/www/hhvm/hostname/htdocs/php5.fcgi
```

netstat also lists hhvm as listening on :::1080 and I can connect to it via telnet

Any Ideas on what I need to change so it works?

Comment: You really should be asking over [sf]

Comment: @Braiam thanks, I just flagged it myself to close it / move it to server fault, and according to what I foound it should be automatically migrated after 5 votes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a IP6 port problem. Try `\[ip6-localhost\]:1080` . Not sure if this has side effects in Apache.

[How do ports work with IPv6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186829/ipv6-and-ports)