# Setup Node.js Server to be accessed externally (external/public ip)

Tags: node.js, ip

I create a node.js server and set it up. It's listening to a port. I can access it through localhost or by other devices on  the network.
Is it possible to access my server by my external ip? Or do I have to find a hosting service to do it for me.

I am able to access the external ip by pinging it, but when I put it up in chrome, it searches for the ip and returns:

> Your search -  - did not match any documents.

Comment: Have you tried using `http://` in front of the ip? Like this: `http://192.168.1.101` There's really no way for us to know how to answer your question without knowing anything about your network. You might need port forwarding. What port is node listening on?

Comment: I used http://. I also listen to ports 80, 8080, and 5555.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the NodeJS was made for that. If you can't access it it's probably a firewall problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I found, was that I didn't put the brackets around the ip. It took me a long time to figure out I needed to do this.

[How do ports work with IPv6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186829/how-do-ports-work-with-ipv6) Answer on how ot search for ipv6 addresses.[1]