# Can I use proxies ipv6 with CasperJS and SlimerJS?

Tags: meteor, proxy, casperjs, ipv6, slimerjs

I have a CasperJS Script duolingo.js and I run the script using a MeteorJS App using a Meteor Method like this:

```
// define server methods so that the clients will have access to server components
Meteor.methods({
  runCasperJS: function() {
    // This method call won't return immediately, it will wait for the
    // asynchronous code to finish, so we call unblock to allow this client
    // to queue other method calls (see Meteor docs)
    this.unblock();
    // run synchonous system command
    var result = process_exec_sync('casperjs duolingo.js --engine=slimerjs --disk-cache=no --proxy=178.166.41.225:80 --proxy-type=HTTP');
    // check for error
    if (result.error) {
      throw new Meteor.Error("exec-fail", "Error running CasperJS: " + result.error.message);
    }
    // success
    return true;
  }
});
```

I need to run the CasperJS Instance using a proxy IP V6. But I don't have any idea, the official documentations of slimerjs and casperjs did not say anything.
Here is the exact part of the code where I use an IP V4 Proxy.

```
  var result = process_exec_sync('casperjs duolingo.js 
--engine=slimerjs --disk-cache=no --proxy=178.166.41.225:80 
--proxy-type=HTTP');
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: What happens if you use an IPv6?

Comment: Hello Mr. Arjom B. I don't know how to use it. I have an ip like this one but does not have port, --proxy=2001:db8:3c4d::/48 . I am very lost in this step.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/186848/1816580?